# Duvidas sobre a apostila da Caelum POO JAVA

Tags: java

Olá, estou estudando a apostila da Caelum de Java Orientação a Objetos e na pagina 131, preciso importar uma lib que peguei desse link: https://github.com/fabiomsnet/fj11-contas/blob/master/lib/fj11-lib-contas.jar 
e ao importar ela e executar esse codigo abaixo dá o erro abaixo.

```
package br.com.caelum.contas.main;

import br.com.caelum.javafx.api.main.OlaMundo;

public class Programa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        OlaMundo.main(args);

    }

}
```

Erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: br/com/caelum/javafx/api/main/OlaMundo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at br.com.caelum.contas.main.Programa.main(Programa.java:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta é simples.
Quando desenvolveram esta biblioteca(lib), utilizaram a versão do Java 8 no desenvolvimento. Com isso as classes contidas na lib foram compiladas no Java 8 e provavelmente a sua JRE é anterior.
A JRE interpreta até códigos anteriores a versão dela(retrocompatibilidade), mas, versões futuras... dá não.
É necessário atualizar a sua versão do Java para ao menos a 8.